# Core Data ordering with a UITableView and NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, ios5, nsorderedset

What are the steps that I need to perform to implement user-defined ordering in a `UITableViewController` with Core Data as the backing store?

Do I still need to respond to `-tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath:toIndexPath:` or is the model re-ordering handled automatically by the table view? Can I just check the "Ordered" checkbox in the Core Data model file and expect it to transmit the changes from the table view to the store, or do I have to do more? Do I have to change the way my `fetchedResultsController` gets it's objects (e.g. add a sort descriptor)?

Answer (score 8):

**You don't need to abandon NSFetchedResultsController or NSOrderedSet**. If you stick with NSOrderedSet, the easy way is to just add a method to your objects NSManagedObject subclass. So for instance, if you have an object Book with an ordered set of Chapters, you can add a method to the Chapters object:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexInBookChapters
{
    NSUInteger index = [self.book.chapters indexOfObject:self];
    return index;
}
```

Tip: Add this to a category so it doesn't get overwritten by CoreData auto generated code.

Then you can use this method in your sort descriptor for your NSFetchedResultsController:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"indexInBookChapters" ascending:YES]];
```

Comment: Are you saying its a bad solution because it doesn't work for some rare scenarios? If I were to model the rare scenario of ordered many-to-many relationships, I would probably just use a third object, say a BookChapterPair, and I would add the indexing properties there. So I could get the indexes via bookChapterPair.indexInBook or bookChapterPair.indexInChapter. Then just set up the NSFetchedResultsController to fetch the BookChapterPair entity instead of Chapter or Book. Easy!

Comment: Your solution is not workable for ordered many-to-many relationships, which are hardly "rare" (except in your example of books and chapters).

Comment: Introducing a third object may have been the only solution before Core Data supported ordered relationships but is nonetheless a little clunky and doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: Actually, in Apple's documentation on Core Data many to many relationships, they recommend a third object for many scenarios, even saying "An advantage of the intermediate entity is that you can also use it to add more information to the relationship—for example a “FriendInfo” entity might include some indication of the strength of the friendship with a “ranking” attribute." In our case the extra information would be the indexes. BTW, I only said it was rare because although I've encountered many uses for many-to-many relationships, I've never run across one that required ordering. Have you?

Comment: It make sense that Apple's documentation would mention the only solution that was possible before iOS 5 introduced ordered relationships in Core Data. But I now find adding a third object to the data model simply to maintain order superfluous. Because the question asked about NSOrderedSet, I also assumed the asker wants to learn to use ordered relationships

Comment: One example of ordered many-to-many relationships is songs belonging to playlists

Comment: You should read the documentation yourself: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10 It doesn't have anything to do with ordered many-to-many, just many-to-many in general. Ie. Even when using NSSet, you often still want a 3rd intermediate object.

Comment: You're right: using a third object has nothing to do with NSOrderSet, thus it does not belong here. (Thanks for the link)

Comment: @RichardVenable, Thanks for your tip about adding a category to a model!

Comment: @RichardVenable Did you tried that? ```NSFetchedResultsController``` will not work with such sort descriptor, if you use SQLite store.

Comment: @Shmidt, yes I use this method but not with an SQLite store. I thought someone else had put a comment previously pointing out that it doesn't work with SQLite, but I don't see that comment anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice here is to NOT use `fetchedResultsController` because it requires a sort descriptor, as you mentioned. You could use a dummy property but this is clearly not good practice. Instead, use `objectAtIndex` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and reload the table data when you need to, perhaps using [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), though depending on your use case there may be simpler and less crash-prone approaches.

And yes, you will have to implement `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath:toIndexPath:`

#### See also

> [NSFetchedResultsController and NSOrderedSet relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758429/nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-nsorderedset-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I'd an an attribute to the Core Data entity, let's say it's an `NSNumber` called `sortOrder`.

When you init a new object in this list, assign the `sortOrder` in increasing order, so that the default sort order is there.

Last, tell your `fetchedResultsController` to use an extra `sortDescriptor` for this sortOrder attribute.

When a  user adjusts the position of an entry, you could set the `sortOrder` to the mean of the entry before and after it.

(Just an idea --- I haven't dealt with this problem or had to implement it, but was considering it for my project down the line.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is what I want to avoid doing. Supposedly, the new APIs in Core Data in iOS 5 will do ordering for you automatically. It's a bit of a hairy problem to implement, especially with re-ordering.

Comment: Nice! I'll have to check in on this question once it gets a good answer then :)

Comment: Also: apparently iCloud does not support ordered data; if you're syncing with iCloud then you are out of luck for that:

"When used with iCloud, there are several limitations with the SQLite store at this time:

Ordered relationships are not supported."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that today too. I can't understand at all why ordering isn't compatible with iCloud, but I'd say it will be in the future. The limitation on data migration is probably the same.

Comment: It's actually incredibly lame that core data doesn't support mapping an ordering + displaying onto tableviews and collectionviews out of the box!