# Trials and tribulations of changing NSOrderedSet order in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have an `NSOrderedSet` attached to a Core Data object that's passed into a `UITableViewController`. The `managedObjectContext` is alive and well in the `UITableViewController` and `myNSOrderedSet` displays properly my `tableView`. When I go to reorder `myNSOrderedSet`, the app crashes. I put a breakpoint in `moveRowAtIndexPath` to see what's going on and everything's fine up until I try to save it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    // BREAKPOINT: "po self.routineToEdit.exercises" shows order is 0, 1, 2
    NSMutableOrderedSet *orderedSet = [self.routineToEdit.exercises mutableCopy];

    [orderedSet exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];

    // BREAKPOINT: "po self.routineToEdit.exercises" shows order is 2, 1, 0
    self.routineToEdit.exercises = orderedSet;

    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext {
    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than passing my object into `MyUITableViewController`, I'm tempted to use a `fetchedResultsController` to grab my object and display it on `MyUITableViewController`. Before I go that route, I'd like to see I can re-order an `NSOrderedSet` with the object that's passed in from `AnotherUITableViewController`.

Here's the console output from my crash:

```
2015-07-12 06:39:53.176 MyApp[26505:1105589] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060dec65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105663bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060deb9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060afabf mutateError + 159
    4   CoreData                            0x000000010591ec26 -[_NSSQLGenerator prepareMasterReorderStatementPart2ForRelationship:] + 118
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010598cfb8 -[NSSQLAdapter newCorrelationMasterReorderStatementPart2ForRelationship:] + 72
    6   CoreData                            0x00000001059a5671 -[NSSQLiteConnection writeCorrelationMasterReordersFromTracker:] + 817
    7   CoreData                            0x00000001059a5f81 -[NSSQLiteConnection writeCorrelationChangesFromTracker:] + 65
    8   CoreData                            0x0000000105997627 -[NSSQLCore writeChanges] + 1351
    9   CoreData                            0x00000001058d32c7 -[NSSQLCore saveChanges:] + 423
    10  CoreData                            0x00000001058a3e74 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 484
    11  CoreData                            0x000000010597ee3f __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 4335
    12  CoreData                            0x0000000105987c30 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 192
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108890614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108876002 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365
    15  CoreData                            0x0000000105979245 _perform + 197
    16  CoreData                            0x00000001058a3a58 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504
    17  CoreData                            0x00000001058cd52d -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1213
    18  MyApp                           0x000000010511083e -[EditRoutineTableViewController saveContext] + 222
    19  MyApp                           0x0000000105110673 -[EditRoutineTableViewController tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:] + 371
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000106817822 -[UITableView _endReorderingForCell:wasCancelled:animated:] + 565
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010682b89d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 462
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000106767958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000106768282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010672e541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010673bcdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010671659c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106012431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060082fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106007934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106007366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a12ba3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    32  UIKit                               0x00000001067198c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    33  MyApp                           0x000000010510a05f main + 111
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001088c4145 start + 1
```

Thank you for reading. I welcome your input.

I found this issue that's in the "same neighborhood" of the problem I'm encountering, however the order of my set is not static like the example given in the example.

[Core Data ordering with a UITableView and NSOrderedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875557/core-data-ordering-with-a-uitableview-and-nsorderedset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackOverflow consensus seems to be there's a bug with how `NSOrderedSet` relationships are handled by Core Data. I was able to manipulate the order of my `NSOrderedSet` using the information contained in Dmitry Makarenko's post on the accessors generated by Xcode:

[Exception thrown in NSOrderedSet generated accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors)

I also cleaned up (at least I think so) the code I used for moving rows in the `UITableView`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSMutableOrderedSet *orderedSet = [self.routineToEdit mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"stretches"].mutableCopy;

    // This is necessary, as exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex doesn't work passing in indexPath.row
    NSInteger fromIndex = fromIndexPath.row;
    NSInteger toIndex = toIndexPath.row;

    // Swap objects at indexes
    [orderedSet exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndex withObjectAtIndex:toIndex];
    NSLog(@"ending orderedSet = /n%@", orderedSet);

    // Assign NSMutableOrderdSet to the object's NSOrderedSet
    self.routineToEdit.stretches = orderedSet;

    // Added performBlockAndWait so the save is complete before doing anything else
    [self.persistentStoreCoordinator performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self saveContext];
    }];

}
```

Saving the object to the `managedObjectContext` right after the UITableView rows/NSObjects are swapped is critical--I discovered this when I saw not all my changes were being saved when I clicked a Done `IBAction` w/ the save method invoked there:

```
[self.persistentStoreCoordinator performBlockAndWait:^{
            [self saveContext];
        }];
```

...but the app still crashed.

Finally, I changed the relationship between BOTH entities to ordered and that did the trick:

[crash on coredata ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863607/crash-on-coredata-ios8)

For my purposes, this is sufficient. I tried each of these fixes independently and none of them worked on a stand-alone basis. At this point, my app works the way I want it to, so I'm going to leave it alone for now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fetch results controller does not give you any advantage here (mainly due to the sorting requirement which does not make sense here).

I would just use the ordered set (the to-many relationship of the object being edited) directly to inform your table view data source. And I would check that assigning the newly ordered ordered set back to the object is working as expected.

Comment: Thank you for helping me rule out an alternate approach. I'm still stumped why everything appears to be performing as expected until I save to the `managedObjectContext`. At this point, I'll wager I'm a method and/or a line or two of code short of getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are already halfway there by calling `mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:`, don't call `mutableCopy` on it! Also, do not reassign this mutable ordered set back to `exercises`. just save your context, call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on the context, and `exercises` should reflect your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your input! That's something I didn't try (and should have). I have it working now, but I encountered the issue when I went to save it to the `managedObjectContext`. When I typed `po self.routineToEdit.exercises` after swapping indexes it printed what I expected. Should I `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` prior to `[self.moc save:&error]`?

Comment: `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` should be called after the save. It tells the object to reload new values from the store.

Comment: Thank you. I incorporated it into the solution I cobbled together this morning.