# Core Data to-many relationship as NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My core data model:

```
Playlist
=======
name

songs (to-many relationship to Song objects, NSOrderedSet)
```

A playlist has multiple songs, and the song order is important.
Using `NSOrderedSet` I can keep the songs order, the problem is when I want to fetch and present a playlist's songs in a table view, I don't know how to use that advantage with a `NSFetchRequest`.

This is how I fetch playlist's songs:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Song"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY playlists = %@", self.playlist];
request.sortDescriptors = // ???
request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

Actually this won't work because the `NSFetchedResultsController` requires a fetch request with sort descriptors.

So I have the songs order, but I can't fetch them according to that order?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, you will need to store the sort order in some other way. Here is a discussion about it: [NSFetchedResultsController and NSOrderedSet relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758429/nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-nsorderedset-relationships)

Answer (score -1):

I've done this in the past:

Add this method to your Song `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexInPlaylist
{
    NSUInteger index = [self.playlist.songs indexOfObject:self];
    return index;
}
```

Then you can use this method in your sort descriptor for your NSFetchedResultsController:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"indexInPlaylist" ascending:YES]];
```

Comment: Then your song relationship is a many-to-many, to be completely honest I've never tried it with that setup.

Comment: That does not work if core data is SQL backed up, I'm getting the followign error: keypath indexInPlaylist not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Song id=1>