# Coredata and NSOrderedSet - how is the order of the set defined?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsorderedset

I had a look through the existing documentation and couldn't find anything that confirms the behaviour I am seeing.

Starting on iOS 5, CoreData relationships can be ordered and in this case the returned object is a NSOrderedSet.

Can anyone confirm that the order of the objects in the set matches the order in which they have been created?

Cheers, 
Rog

Comment: Look out for this bug on NSOrderedSet - you need to override in order to make removals work:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7922993/1046685

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Damien!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't sort the order yourself using `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` then I believe the objects are sorted in the order in which they are added.

You can also manual set the order with with `– insertObject:atIndex:` .

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableOrderedSet

Answer (score 1):

You should create a NSMutabledOrderedSet with data from your old NSOrderedSet, make your changes and move your data back again:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *orderedSet = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] initWithSet:[self.myOrderedSet set]];
[orderedSet insertObject:newObject atIndex:index];
self.myOrderedSet = orderedSet;
```