# CoreDataGeneratedAccessor method giving "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

When i call the method:

```
- (void)removeObjectFromMediaAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

which is one of the default methods in a file created as a core data object, i'm getting an error of `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. Anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error message? If we know what selector was sent it may give us a clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure that your NSManagedObject sublcass instance was created using an NSManagedObjectContext and not directly.  Instead of leveraging @synthesize for properties, NSManagedObject sublcasses leverage the @dynamic keyword which indicates the accessors will be created at runtime - in this case, by the NSManagedObjectContext.  They will not be there if you create the object instance using something like alloc]init];

Comment: could you please elaborate on this? Could you please show me an example? I use 
`[[ENTITY alloc] initWithEntity:[self getEntityDescription:[ENTITY className]] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];`
but this seems to be the wrong way according to you.

Comment: What you are doing is not wrong, just different from either method I was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

It is a notorious Core Data bug. It is almost 2-year old but sadly it is still there. See this post: [Exception thrown in NSOrderedSet generated accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have altered your data model without altering the classes, or vice-versa.  Or perhaps one of your team members did (my team quickly learned about this danger).  Another possibility is that the reference you are using is not actually the class you think it is.  Sometimes if you overrelease an object, another object will occupy the previous memory space but it will not be the correct class.

However, this doesn't look like a default method.  The default methods I am used to seeing are add object, remove object, change to a new NSSet, and one more that I can't quite remember off the top of my head.  However, if you got the CoreData object to use an NSArray instead it would make sense.