# Core Data declared remove<key>ItemsAtIndex method results in unrecognized selector

Tags: core-data

I have a Core Data "List" entity that has an ordered relationship to ListItems.

Core Data itself, generates a method in the .h,

```
- (void)removeListItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
```

However, when I attempt to invoke that method, at runtime the app crashes stating its an unrecognized selector.

Is this method really not implemented? Why would Core Data declare it if its not implemented? Am I supposed to do something else to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at this post:
[problems-with-nsorderedset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/problems-with-nsorderedset)

it's lion app, but i think the problem is same.