# How to add element to NSOrderedSet for Core Data?

Tags: ios5, core-data, nsorderedset

I did some studies on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors/7922993#7922993). But none of its solution work for me. Let me explain what I did:

[image]

It's actually very similar with the mentioned post.

Category.h

```
@class Category, Item;

@interface Category : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *items;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Category *parentcategory;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *subcategories;

@end

@interface Category (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)insertObject:(Item *)value inItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertItems:(NSArray *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)replaceItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withItems:(NSArray *)values;
- (void)addItemsObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)removeItemsObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)addItems:(NSOrderedSet *)values;
- (void)removeItems:(NSOrderedSet *)values;
- (void)addSubcategoriesObject:(Category *)value;
- (void)removeSubcategoriesObject:(Category *)value;
- (void)addSubcategories:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSubcategories:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

In my view controller, I load one of the category:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:kEntityCategory];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor
                                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:kAttributeCategoryName ascending:YES
                                                    selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

NSError *error = nil;
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

NSArray* data = [appDelegate.dataCenter.document.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if ( data.count > 0)
{
    self.category = [data objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

I have a button in navigation bar for testing purpose. When it's clicked I'll copy the first item and add to the end.

```
Item* item = [self.category.items objectAtIndex:0];

[self.category willChangeValueForKey:@"items"];
NSMutableOrderedSet *tempSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:self.category.items];
[tempSet addObject: item];
self.category.items = tempSet;
[self.category didChangeValueForKey:@"items"];
```

The problem is the item is not added to database at all. (I did some testing, for example, I modify the item content. It proves that the database has no problem at all.) But I don't know the reason why the item is not to the database. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: I can use the NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName to add new Item to the end of the items.

But it doesn't solve my problem because I have no way to insert the new item in the middle of my items in category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved. There are two problems:

1. Can't insert/add an existing item
2. I have a stupid name conflict. So the suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors/7922993#7922993) is good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Swift:

```
let mutableItems = items.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet
mutableItems.addObject(anItem)
items = mutableItems.copy() as! NSOrderedSet
```

Objective-C:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *mutableItems = (NSMutableOrderedSet *)items.mutableCopy;
[mutableItems addObject:anItem];
items = (NSOrderedSet *)mutableItems.copy;
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to have `mutableItems` be a constant using "let." While the ordered set is mutable, the pointer to the object is not going to change so it is better to make constant.

Comment: Hey! In swift you should use `let` (as @Garrett said) and force downcast: 

    `let mutableItems = items.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet`

    `mutableItems.addObject(anItem)`

    `items = mutableItems.copy() as! NSOrderedSet`

Comment: @PaulSlm Updated, Swift is changing so fast!

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this is with the `mutableOrderedSetValueForKey` function in NSKeyValueCoding. You could say

`owningObject.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("items").addObject(anItem)`

Unfortunately, this doesn't get you the compile-time checking of "items."

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5 and Above

```
let mutableItems = items.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet
mutableItems.add(anItem)
items = mutableItems.copy() as! NSOrderedSet
```