# removeObjectFromSetAtIndex, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data

I just started using an `NSOrderedSet` with Core Data, and the first object I try to add, it fails.  I found this post describing the failure:  [Exception thrown in NSOrderedSet generated accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors)

Now I want to remove an object at a specific index.  I get unrecognized selector sent to instance when I call the generated Core Data method.  For me it looks like:

```
removeObjectFromAddressAnnotationsAtIndex:
```

I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is also a bug for this generated method as well.  When I stepped through, I saw my index did line up with what I expected so I'm not sure what it is.

Edit:

I use it like so:

```
[_route removeAddressAnnotationsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexToRemove]];
[_route removeObjectFromAddressAnnotationsAtIndex:indexToRemove];
```

I've tried both, and both fail with this error:

```
[Route removeAddressAnnotationsAtIndexes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xea71980
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Route removeAddressAnnotationsAtIndexes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xea71980'
```

Comment: can you show the code you are using and the exact error?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I added the code you requested.

Comment: It doesn't look like the known bug in generated accessors, since `Route` doesn't appear to be responding to that selector. Are you sure that the method naming is correct and that the relationship is `to-many` in the core data model editor?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Ya I just checked, it says M (to-many) for my Route entity.  I also copied and pasted the method when I tried using it.  I also am able to jump to the definition on those methods and I end up going to my Route.h file.  But knowing that there is no known bug for this, then I'll just keep digging.  Thanks!

Comment: Try to override that method with your own implementation, place a breakpoint in it an see whether it gets called.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yes if I override it with my own implementation, it does get called.  I copied and pasted the generated accessor from the .h to the .m and just added a log.  My log does get to the console.

Comment: So those methods are not being generated at all by Core Data. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pretty much given up on `NSOrderedSet`. They are a bit unwieldy being neither derived from `NSArray` nor from `NSSet`, so a lot of the usual functionality is simply not available.

In my Core Data models, I have included a `position` or `order` attribute to keep track of the order. Simple and reliable.