# Core Data Fetch limited to objects within a relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Given the following core data model:

```
EntityA <--->> EntityB <--->> EntityC
```

I already have fetched the required `EntityA` in a first `TableViewController`. When selecting a row, the user goes to a second ViewController, following the relationship. This second view has a `@property EntityB *entityB`. In this second view, there are controls that will modify attributes of `EntityC`. So if `EntityB` has 4 `EntityC`, there will be 4 sliders. Each slider modify an attribute of one of the `EntityC`.

My question is: what's the best way to select the right EntityC? The following predicate

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityC" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entityB == %@ AND rank == <#some number#>", self.entityB];
```

returns the correct value. But isn't this overkill when selecting 1 out of 4 entities?

Comment: Surely you already have them relationship contents to set the initial slider value?

Comment: Very good question. But in this case, I need initial values to always be default values (50 on a 0 to 100 scale).

Comment: Is the relationship ordered?

Comment: No... Can it be ordered according to an attribute of the target entity? (From EntityB, EntityC are ordered based on a attribute of EntityC?)

Comment: The order is set when you create / add to the relationship (so you can choose).

Comment: What do you mean by 'select the right EntityC' ?  Can't you simply associate the items in the entityB.children (NSSet) with the controls themselves such that any movement of the slider will automatically update the associated entityC

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald: how would you associate entityB.children with the control? And what I mean is entityC with rank x should go with slider x. So when the slider x is set to a new value, the corresponding EntityC is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an ordered relationship then you can just get the appropriate object directly. If not then you need to use a predicate (though you could run it on the relationship (if small count) or the MOC (if large count).

Comment: I will implement this solution and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer did work. So I will accept it. But FYI, I ran into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors). The workaround worked, but I may refactor and try something else...

Comment: [That issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors) is one of the reasons for my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I have had bad experience with ordered relationships. Rearranging is error prone, and you do not have many of the advantages of either `NSSet` or `NSArray` because `NSOrderedSet` is derived from neither.

Instead, add a `position` attribute to `EntityC`. This seems to me the most straight-forward way to do it. And no, IMO this is not overkill even with a handful of instances. Now you can sort and identify the relationship entities quite easily.

Comment: Is your warning still valid if I'm not going to re-arrange them? Right now it seems to be the best idea...