# Core Data error: 'Unacceptable type of value for ordered to-many relationship'

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm a beginner working with Core Data for iOS. I'm trying to create a library kind of function here, but I'm getting this message:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
    'Unacceptable type of value for ordered to-many relationship: property 
    = "studenthistory"; desired type = NSOrderedSet; given type = __NSSetI; 
    value = {(
      <NSManagedObject: 0x8cacd20> (entity: StudentHistory; id: 0x8cacd80 
      <x-coredata:///StudentHistory/tE710FEAD-C78E-4C91-8F38-23BDC5AA2C943> ; 
      data: {
        bookid = 5;
        checkin = 6;
        checkout = 7;
        open = TBA;
        student = nil;
```

The relationship is Student --> (to many) --> StudentHistory.

I can only guess, but I suspect that the problem is occurring trying to set one object while it is expecting more, because it is a `NSSet`?

Here is the code:

```
...
StudentHistory *stuhist = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"StudentHistory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

stuhist.bookid = _bookidTextField.text;
stuhist.checkout = _checkoutTextField.text;
stuhist.checkin = _checkinTextField.text;
stuhist.open = @"TBA";

newStu.studenthistory = [NSSet setWithObject:stuhist];
newStu.studenthistory = [NSSet setWithObject:stuhist];


NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"UH OH! Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: You have defined "studenthistory" as an *ordered* to-many
relationship and therefore have to assign an `NSOrderedSet` to it:

```
newStu.studenthistory = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObject:stuhist];
```

Alternatively, set the *inverse relationship*:

```
stuhist.student = newStu;
```

(Note that the automatically generated accessor methods for *ordered* relationships
still have bugs. For a description of the problem and workarounds, see
[Exception thrown in NSOrderedSet generated accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors).)

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a significant advantage for ordered relationship vs non ordered?

Comment: @user2951: It's the other way around: an ordered relationship has some disadvantages. In addition to the above-mentioned bug, it cannot be used with iCloud. Therefore, unless you really need the relationship to be ordered, I would always choose an unordered relationship.