# Inverse Relationship with Core Data Causes Crash when Adding Object to NSSet

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, relationships

I have 2 entities in Core Data, a `Bill` and `Person`.  I have two relationships:

- `Bill` to `Person` is a 'To Many' relationship called 'people'
- The inverse - from `Person` to `Bill` is 'To One'- called 'bill'.

The result generated by Xcode (along with the classes) are:

`Bill`:

```
extension Bill {
    @NSManaged var people: NSSet?
}
```

`Person`:

```
extension Person {
    @NSManaged var bill: Bill?
}
```

This is the method I've written to add a `Person` object to the `Bill`'s `NSSet`:

```
class Bill : NSManagedObject {
...

func addPersonToBill(contact : CNContact){

        let entDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext())

// Create Person object with custom initialiser
        let person = Person(contact: contact, entity: entDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext())
        print("Got person")

        people = people?.setByAddingObject(person) // CRASHES HERE
    }
}
```

The custom initialiser for **Person** is:

```
init(contact : CNContact, entity : NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context : NSManagedObjectContext?){
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
   // I set other properties here using info from the CNContact
    }
```

However, when I add a `Person`, it crashes at `people?.setByAddingObject(person)` with the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray
>   isEqualToSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc7ed875cb0'

When I delete the `bill` relationship from `Person` to `Bill`, it runs fine and the `Person` is added to the `Bill`'s 'people' `NSSet`.  I could leave it like this as I don't necessarily need this inverse relationship, but I've read that it is best to have an inverse relationship unless I have a good reason not to.  I also face this issue with other relationships in my app, so I would have a lot of relationships without their inverse.

Any ideas what's wrong?  Are my relationships incorrect? One `Bill` can have many `Person`s, but one `Person` can only have one `Bill`.

The solutions I've tried are:

- Adding this accessor from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321026/4834558):

  `@NSManaged func addPeopleObject(value:Person)`

But I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]:
>   set argument is not an NSSet'

- Creating an `NSMutableOrderedSet` as suggested by other answers:

`let mutPeople = NSMutableOrderedSet(array: (people?.allObjects)!)
mutOwers.addObject(person)
people = NSSet(array:mutPeople.array)`

...but I get the same, original crash message.

- Unwrapping 'people' - still get the same crash message.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try unwrapping your `people` property.  Something like `if let people = self.people as? NSSet { self.people = people.setByAddingObject(person) } else { self.people = NSSet(object:person) }`

Comment: @Paulw11 I get the same error :/

Comment: If you set a breakpoint and look at `people` what class is it?  The exception indicates that Swift is converting it to a `SwiftDeferredNSArray` rather than a set

Comment: @Paulw11 Hmm... when I unwrap `people` and print its `dynamicType` it says it's `_NSFaultingMutableSet`, so it's not an `NSArray` like the error seems to say

Comment: I think the exception is occurring somewhere inside Core Data as a result of your update rather than directly in that line of code

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah, I just figured out what I did wrong.  Silly mistake on my end, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I've posted an answer below.  :)

Comment: I am interested as to why you had to write code to manage the relationships.  Simply assigning `person.bill=bill` should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I had a similar problem as [this question].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291760/swift-and-coredata-problems-with-relationship-nsset-nsset-intersectsset)  I had a method on `Bill` called `getOwers` which had a return type of an array, and this seemed to override the accessor CoreData creates.  I changed the method to `getOwersArr`, and all is fine now.  Thanks to @Paulw11 for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I also have to-many relationships implemented as `NSSet`. I add/delete objects to the set (without any problems) using code like the following:

```
let mutableSet = bill.mutableSetValueForKey("people") 

mutableSet.addObject(newPerson)

// (next, save managed object context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with iOS 9.3 in a one-to-many relationship.

I fixed it by replacing:

`group.addToTeams(team) // Crashes on iOS 9.3`

with:

`team.group = group // This will correctly add team to the set without crashing`

Basically instead of adding and object to the set use the Inverse relationship.