# How to move related objects from one object to another in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am running into troubles with some database operations in CoreData. Sometimes the views are refreshed in the middle of the process and show wrong states. Sometimes data is even lost.

I have the following CoreData object model:

Course has many Students

Now I want to merge two courses A and B together so that afterwards all the students of course B should be assigned to course A and course B does not exist anymore.

(A student is in exactly one course)

Currently I’m doing it this way, which works most of the time but has the described problems:

```
Course courseA = [self someCourse];
Course courseB = [self someOtherCourse];

for (Student *student in courseB.students) {
    student.course = courseA;
}

[managedObjectContext deleteObject:courseB];

NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
if(error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Deletion of Course failed.");
}
```

Sometimes I get the following error in the device log:

```
Core Data: warning: validation recovery attempt FAILED with Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)" UserInfo=0x1d97f8e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.), Dangling reference to an invalid object.=null, NSValidationErrorObject=<Course: 0x1cad56c0> (entity: Course; id: 0x1ca69380 <x-coredata:///Course/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D3519> ; data: {
    endDateTime = "2014-09-18 17:38:17 +0000";
    place = "0x1db4c120 <x-coredata:///Place/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D7394>";
    room = "0x18d696a0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Room/p1>";
    category = "0x18e8f990 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/CDCategory/p1>";
    changed = "2014-09-19 08:04:03 +0000";
    startDateTime = "2014-09-18 17:30:01 +0000";
    syncInfos = "<relationship fault: 0x1cbb5bb0 'syncInfos'>";
    students =     (
        "0x18d073c0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461393>",
        "0x1c911b00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461383>",
        "0x1c915770 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461401>",
        "0x1a0a6560 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461387>",
        "0x1c90e2f0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461346>",
        "0x1cd7fc00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461370>",
        "0x1a0bdbf0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461374>",
        "0x1cb11090 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461395>",
        "0x1cf31fc0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461379>",
        "0x1cda6230 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461339>",
        "(...and 133 more...)"
    );
}), NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(
    "<Student: 0x1cf6c000> (entity: Student; id: 0x1a36fc70 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461431> ; data: <fault>)"
), NSValidationErrorKey=students, NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship 'students' on managed object (0x1cad56c0) <Course: 0x1cad56c0> (entity: Course; id: 0x1ca69380 <x-coredata:///Course/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D3519> ; data: {
    endDateTime = "2014-09-18 17:38:17 +0000";
    place = "0x1db4c120 <x-coredata:///Place/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D7394>";
    room = "0x18d696a0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Room/p1>";
    category = "0x18e8f990 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/CDCategory/p1>";
    changed = "2014-09-19 08:04:03 +0000";
    startDateTime = "2014-09-18 17:30:01 +0000";
    syncInfos = "<relationship fault: 0x1cbb5bb0 'syncInfos'>";
    students =     (
        "0x18d073c0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461393>",
        "0x1c911b00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461383>",
        "0x1c915770 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461401>",
        "0x1a0a6560 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461387>",
        "0x1c90e2f0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461346>",
        "0x1cd7fc00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461370>",
        "0x1a0bdbf0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461374>",
        "0x1cb11090 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461395>",
        "0x1cf31fc0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461379>",
        "0x1cda6230 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461339>",
        "(...and 133 more...)"
    );
}) with objects {(
    <Student: 0x1d9e48d0> (entity: Student; id: 0x18d073c0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461393> ; data: <fault>),
    <Student: 0x1ddc6920> (entity: Student; id: 0x1c911b00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461383> ; data: <fault>),
    <Student: 0x1d991750> (entity: Student; id: 0x1c915770 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461455> ; data: <fault>),
    <Student: 0x1cf6c000> (entity: Student; id: 0x1a36fc70 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461431> ; data: <fault>)
)}, NSValidationErrorShouldAttemptRecoveryKey=true} and {
    "Dangling reference to an invalid object." = "<null>";
    NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey =     (
        "<Student: 0x1cf6c000> (entity: Student; id: 0x1a36fc70 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461431> ; data: <fault>)"
    );
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)";
    NSValidationErrorKey = students;
    NSValidationErrorObject = "<Course: 0x1cad56c0> (entity: Course; id: 0x1ca69380 <x-coredata:///Course/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D3519> ; data: {\n    endDateTime = \"2014-09-18 17:38:17 +0000\";\n    place = \"0x1db4c120 <x-coredata:///Place/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D7394>\";\n    room = \"0x18d696a0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Room/p1>\";\n    category = \"0x18e8f990 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/CDCategory/p1>\";\n    changed = \"2014-09-19 08:04:03 +0000\";\n    startDateTime = \"2014-09-18 17:30:01 +0000\";\n    points = 1436;\n    done = 1;\n    notes = \"\";\n    syncInfos = \"<relationship fault: 0x1cbb5bb0 'syncInfos'>\";\n    students =     (\n        \"0x18d073c0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461393>\",\n        \"0x1c911b00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461383>\",\n        \"0x1c915770 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461401>\",\n        \"0x1a0a6560 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461387>\",\n        \"0x1c90e2f0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461346>\",\n        \"0x1cd7fc00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461370>\",\n        \"0x1a0bdbf0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461374>\",\n        \"0x1cb11090 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461395>\",\n        \"0x1cf31fc0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461379>\",\n        \"0x1cda6230 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461339>\",\n        \"(...and 133 more...)\"\n    );\n})";
    NSValidationErrorShouldAttemptRecoveryKey = 1;
    NSValidationErrorValue = "Relationship 'students' on managed object (0x1cad56c0) <Course: 0x1cad56c0> (entity: Course; id: 0x1ca69380 <x-coredata:///Course/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D3519> ; data: {\n    endDateTime = \"2014-09-18 17:38:17 +0000\";\n    place = \"0x1db4c120 <x-coredata:///Place/tA8FBABB4-2BBD-4A5D-ADFA-94D6F08F6A6D7394>\";\n    room = \"0x18d696a0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Room/p1>\";\n    category = \"0x18e8f990 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/CDCategory/p1>\";\n    changed = \"2014-09-19 08:04:03 +0000\";\n    startDateTime = \"2014-09-18 17:30:01 +0000\";\n    points = 1436;\n    done = 1;\n    notes = \"\";\n    syncInfos = \"<relationship fault: 0x1cbb5bb0 'syncInfos'>\";\n    students =     (\n        \"0x18d073c0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461393>\",\n        \"0x1c911b00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461383>\",\n        \"0x1c915770 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461401>\",\n        \"0x1a0a6560 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461387>\",\n        \"0x1c90e2f0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461346>\",\n        \"0x1cd7fc00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461370>\",\n        \"0x1a0bdbf0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461374>\",\n        \"0x1cb11090 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461395>\",\n        \"0x1cf31fc0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461379>\",\n        \"0x1cda6230 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461339>\",\n        \"(...and 133 more...)\"\n    );\n}) with objects {(\n    <Student: 0x1d9e48d0> (entity: Student; id: 0x18d073c0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461393> ; data: <fault>),\n    <Student: 0x1ddc6920> (entity: Student; id: 0x1c911b00 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461383> ; data: <fault>),\n    <Student: 0x1d991750> (entity: Student; id: 0x1c915770 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461433> ; data: <fault>),\n    <Student: 0x1dbb38f0> (entity: Student; id: 0x1c920ba0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461435> ; data: <fault>),\n    <Student: 0x1cf7b780> (entity: Student; id: 0x1c9298f0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461436> ; data: <fault>),\n    <Student: 0x1dd3f4f0> (entity: Student; id: 0x1a09a3b0 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461454> ; data: <fault>),\n    <Student: 0x1d9e4850> (entity: Student; id: 0x1cbbe040 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461455> ; data: <fault>),\n    <Student: 0x1cf6c000> (entity: Student; id: 0x1a36fc70 <x-coredata://16CBD0F6-B399-4A9C-BD51-5EC98BD99EFC/Student/p461431> ; data: <fault>)\n)}";
}.
```

Answer (score 2):

what kind of delete rule do you have in your relationShip definition for Student.course (probably : "no action". I think it should be "Nullify").
Dangling reference to an invalid object are generally related with improperly set relationship technically. And also just to be sure I'll add this : courseB.students.**copy** in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, Student.course has delete-rule "Nullify" and Course.students has delete rule Cascade, using a copy to iterate over is a good tipp, will add that

Answer (score 1):

If the problem only occures, when views are reloaded while processing the change, then you have the option to cache Data and synchronize your read and write steps, and/or you refresh the views only in a stable state (so the migration method send a notification when it's done).

If it also occures in other states, you should check your options in the model (synchronization, validation, delete-rules) or try first saving the migrated students and then delete.

If still not working, could you provide a screenshot of the model and the relations?

btw, why iterating every user instead of using

```
[courseB addStudents:courseA.students];
```

? Of course only if you have the `CoreDataGeneratedAccessors` that would be in your case:

```
@interface Course (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addStudentsObject:(Student *)value;
- (void)removeStudentsObject:(Student *)value;
- (void)addStudents:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeStudents:(NSSet *)value;

@end
```

Comment: I had to iterate over them because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors