# How to replace all ordered to-many relationships in NSManagedObject ios

Tags: ios, one-to-many, nsmanagedobject

First, please note, I'm aware of the [NSOrderedSet bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors/7922993).

I think the issue I have is that I don't fully understand `removeXXX:(NSOrderedSet*)values`.

I want to replace and old ordered set with a new ordered set of objects.

What I would have thought is:

```
[object removeXXX];
[object addXXX:newSet];
```

So I don't understand the values passed to `removeXXX:`

Is it possible to merely set the property?:

```
object.relation = newSet;
```