# NSPredicate SUBQUERY results in: [NSMutableSet unionSet] set argument is not an NSSet

Tags: objective-c, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

On an array of Artists I am trying to do `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` using the below format to only remain with Artists that have at least one Album that has at least one Intro song.

`albums` is a to many relationship from Artist to Album. `intros` is a to many relationship from Album to Intro. I get an exception saying `[NSMutableSet unionSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet`. What am I doing wrong? Here is the aforementioned predicate format:

```
@"SUBQUERY(albums, $alb, ANY $alb.intros != NULL).@count != 0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is/was a  bug in apples Core-data framework. I confirm this because I do not encounter this issue anymore. I did not address it at all. I tried to, and that reduced the frequency of the exception, but did not extinguish it.

Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7385439/948021) for suggestions on how to solve this sort of issue.