# Crashing when using 'filteredSetUsingPredicate' on CoreData NSSet (NSInvalidArgumentException: set argument is not an NSSet)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsset

Let's say I have NSManagedObject Zoo, and he got connection oneToMany to 'Cat' named cats, this connection is NSSet.
When I use the function '[filteredSetUsingPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/filteredSetUsingPredicate:)', I get a crash with the following code:

```
Zoo *zoo = //intance of our zoo with all the animals - from core data 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"catSize == Big"];
NSArray *arrayOfCats = [zoo.cats filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The crash stack is as follow:

```
Terminating app due to an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableSet unionSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
1  CoreFoundation                 0x180f51798 -[NSMutableSet unionSet:] + 96
2  CoreData                       0x182f24154 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] + 716
3  CoreData                       0x182f05f10 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet count] + 28
4  Foundation                     0x181a93828 -[NSSet(NSPredicateSupport) filteredSetUsingPredicate:] + 68
```

This happens only once in a while, and probably has to do with updates and deletion that I do in the background context (adding or deleting cats if I stick to this example).
Any idea how can I protect my application from crashing? Any access to the property cats cause a crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSPredicate SUBQUERY results in: \[NSMutableSet unionSet\] set argument is not an NSSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992832/nspredicate-subquery-results-in-nsmutableset-unionset-set-argument-is-not-an)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the relationship delete rule make sure its setup correctly