# Core data [NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2

I have two tables with relations.

[image]

At ShopItem class trying to save product:

```
let productEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Product", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
                    product = Product(entity: productEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)

if let product_title:String = jsonObj["product_title"] as? String {
                        product.setValue(product_title, forKey: "product_title")
                    } else {
                        product.setValue("", forKey: "product_title")
                    }

                    product.setValue(self, forKey: "shopitem")
                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext!.save()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
```

`jsonObj` - it is a json response from server.

And get an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'
```

Comment: here is the answer:[a link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors

Comment: I have this problem. Only works on iPad and does not work on iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

I solved problem by adding `@objc(Product)` to my class.

```
@objc(Product)
class Product: NSManagedObject {
    ...
}
```

Can anyone explain what does this mean ?